# Xpath - How to select a node but not its child nodes

Tags: xpath, jdom

I am trying to select a node but not any of its child nodes.

Example Input:

```
<Header attr1="Hello"> 
  <child1> hello </child1>
  <child2>world</child2>
</Header>
```

Expected Output: `<Header attr1="Hello"> </Header>`

Code:

```
Document xmlDoc = saxBuilder.build(inputStream);
Xpath x = XPath.newInstance("/Header");
eleMyElement = x.selectSingleNode(xmlDoc);
XMLOutputter output = new XMLOutputter();
output.outputString(eleMyElement) --> this is the output
```

I tried with /Header as XPath, it gives me the header along with child nodes.

Comment: XPath selects what's in the document.  There is no `Header` element without children in your document.  Typically XSLT would be used to construct an output document from parts of an input document.  With likely more effort, you could use another API such as that provided by JDOM to achieve the same result.  It will take more than just XPath, though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish what is selected from what is displayed.

The XPath expression `/Header` selects one node only, the `Header` element. You say "it gives me", but what is "it"? Something is displaying the results of the XPath selection, and it is choosing to display the results by rendering the selected element with all its children. You need to look at the code that is displaying the result.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added the code I used. I am trying to change the xpath to find a way to exclude the child nodes.

Comment: Changing the XPath won't help. The XPath is only selecting the node that you want. You need to change the call on `output.outputString(eleMyElement)` so it only displays the information you want displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can simply do

```
eleMyElement.getContent().clear();
```

and all child nodes will be deleted.